# Laravel 8 Redirect back to same page after changing locale

Tags: php, laravel, localization

Hello i have one problem
when i change local language its redirecting me on home page
when i'm on news/some-news page and then i change language its redirecting me to home page

how can i change that and stay in current page?

```
Route::group([
  'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
  'middleware' => [
    'localeSessionRedirect',
    'localizationRedirect',
  ]
]);
```

```
<select class="language-arrow cursor-pointer font-size-14 text-blue-100 bg-body pr-15px pl-5px w-100px rounded-sm" name="" id="switcher">
  <option class="d-none" value="" disabled>ენა</option>
  <option value="/ge" selected="selected" class="font-size-14 bg-dark-blue text-white">@tr('web.ge')</option>
  <option value="/en" class="font-size-14 bg-dark-blue text-white">@tr('web.en')</option>
  <option value="/ru" class="font-size-14 bg-dark-blue text-white">@tr('web.ru')</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can anyone please help me with this problem

Comment: It seems like you have used a package to help you. Perhaps you could add the used package to your question.

Comment: "mcamara/laravel-localization": "^1.6",

Comment: Perhaps you could add this to your question so that is clear for other people what package you are using? In any case, reading throug the [documentation](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization#localized-urls), You can use the function in your blade file: {{ LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL('yourLocaleHere') }}  to create a URL that links to the current URL, but only changing the locale. Hope this helps.

Comment: thnx a lot <3 its worked {{ LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL('yourLocaleHere') }} thnx agian :  )

Comment: @EricLandheer you should post that as answer so it can be flagged as correct

Comment: @Irakli Answer was posted, you can flag it as correct to help others with the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using [Laravel Localization](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization) package.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization#localized-urls), you can localize URL's using the following function (change `en` to the required locale):

```
// Returns current url with English locale.
{{ LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL('en') }}
```

This will create a URL to the current URL, but changing the locale part of the URL to the provided locale.